# Izito and similar sites keeps appearing in my google search results

Tags: security, malware

Izito and similar sites keep appearing on my search engine results.  It started a few weeks ago.  It has been happening on both - my Ubuntu and Windows computer, and even on a new Windows computer.  It has been happening on Chrome and Microsoft Edge and on Google and Bing.  I have since installed Bitdefender AV and done factory resets and it still keeps coming back after a while.  I was wondering if someone could please advise on what might be causing it, what damage / impact it might (have) caused, and how I could get rid of it.

Comment: Please share a screenshot how it looks like. Please also inspect with web tools (F12) if what you see really comes as reply from your request. If it is soemthing malicious I would expect this to be running on your computer and not come from a http response.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Izito is a browser hijacker and also a spyware. It probably got installed from some shady executable you have launched.

- The first thing you should probably do is uninstall whatever shady software you have. If you remember when the weird events happened you could sort the installed programs by their installation date to make your search easier.
- Check your browser shortcut properties, since they might run the unwanted page by default.
- Perform a Full antivirus scan (you could try using another AV like MalwareBytes which has a free trial)
- If the browsers are still showing the unwanted pages (which is probable), you will need to change the default landing page and extensions/add-ons in the settings. Remove all extensions you do not recall installing yourself.

There's more information about this topic in: https://www.2-spyware.com/remove-izito-com-virus.html

In terms of damage/impact caused, it could have monitored your web traffic and browsing history, stolen passwords and cookies from browsers, modified security parameters in your browsers and installed more unwanted add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I checked the network-connections in google devtools and discovered a json object, containing all the Izito-Ads in my search results. Here is the exact code:

```
[{"title":"Such Enum - Top Ergebnisse aus dem Web","desc":"Finden Sie Enum. Besuchen Sie ZapMeta & Bekomm Relevante Info.","url":"www.zapmeta.de\/Search_The_Web","click":"https:\/\/g.httpsweb.com\/?id=19973832&hash=2df186454adf7fb48cbdd0856b522b22&url=www.zapmeta.de%2FSearch_The_Web&dst=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zapmeta.de%2Fws%3Fq%3Denum%26sc%3Dn"},{"title":"Dart - Such Dart","desc":"Dart Erhalten. Millionen Ergebnisse hier Entdecken!","url":"www.izito.de\/Dart\/Gute_Ergebnisse","click":"https:\/\/g.httpsweb.com\/?id=19973832&hash=0ab3db0695aa777c657374553107809b&url=www.izito.de%2FDart%2FGute_Ergebnisse&dst=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.izito.de%2Fws%3Fq%3Ddart%26sc%3Dn"},{"title":"Enum Domains - Such Enum Domains","desc":"Finden Sie Enum Domains. Suche Schneller, Besser & Schlauer bei ZapMeta!","url":"www.zapmeta.de\/Such","click":"https:\/\/g.httpsweb.com\/?id=19973832&hash=470a944e9a24d38ffcae00f520be92a9&url=www.zapmeta.de%2FSuch&dst=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zapmeta.de%2Fws%3Fq%3Denum%2520domains%26sc%3Dn"},{"title":"Enum Domain - Such Enum Domain","desc":"Bekomm Enum Domain. Erhalte Qualit\u00e4tsergebnisse bei iZito!","url":"www.izito.de\/Enum+Domain","click":"https:\/\/g.httpsweb.com\/?id=19973832&hash=547cdea46d148bc1515b606002e1fb5b&url=www.izito.de%2FEnum%2BDomain&dst=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.izito.de%2Fws%3Fq%3Denum%2520domain%26sc%3Dn"}]
```

This json was loaded from https://g.httpsweb.com/. So I solved this problem, by adding a new outbound rule to my windows defender, which blocks all communication with the IP, that belongs to this url.

Comment: It would be really helpful if could explain how you added a new outbound rule to your windows defender.

Comment: It was explained pretty good right here: https://theitbros.com/windows-defender-firewall-with-advanced-security/ The explanation on how to create outbound rules starts at the middle of the page